# rendered called before DOM completion - meteor blaze

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am creating a dynamic form using json and trying to use jquery-validation plugin to add validation rules to input fields.

Json structure and helper method is :

```
var fields = [{
    label: "Name",
    type: {name: 'STRING'},
    validationRules: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 100,
        minlength: 3
    }
},{
    label: "Currency",
    type: {name: 'CHECKBOX'},
    defaultValue: ['USD', 'INR'],
    validationRules: {
        required: true
    },
    sourceCollection: 'oNLFfi4L3zgNLhScv',
}] ;

Template.eventCreate.helpers({
    fields: function(){
        console.log("calling fields");
        fields.forEach(function(field, index){
            field.sourceCollectionData = StaticLists.find({_id: field.sourceCollection});
        });
        return fields;
    }
});
```

Template looks like:

```
<template name="eventCreate">
    <form id="newEventForm" class="form-horizontal">
        {{#each fields}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">{{label}}</label>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    {{#if equals type.name 'STRING'}}
                        <input name="{{label}}" id="{{label}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter {{label}}" value="{{defaultValue}}" />
                    {{/if}}
                    {{#if equals type.name 'CHECKBOX'}}
                        {{#each sourceCollectionData}}
                            {{#if isActive}}
                                <div class="col-xs-2 checkbox">
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="{{../label}}" id="{{../label}}" value="{{name}}" {{checked ../defaultValue}}> {{name}}
                                    </label>
                                </div> 
                            {{/if}}                               
                        {{/each}}                         
                    {{/if}}
                </div>               
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </form>
</template>
```

Now I am trying to add validation rule in rendered method:

```
Template.eventCreate.rendered = function(){
    $('#newEventForm').validate({
       ....
    });

    fields.forEach(function(field, index){
        if(field.validationRules){
            $('#'+field.label).rules('add', field.validationRules);
        }
    });
}
```

It works in case of input text but throws exception for checkbox because checkbox DOM is still not laid out and there is no element with id "Currency".

I assume in meteor blaze rendered is called once only when DOM rendering is complete. Though it is called once here but before DOM rendering completes.

### EDIT

Earlier I was hardcoding the JSON in js file itself and now I am retrieving it from mongo.

But its seems that rendered callback is invoked only first time and not invoked every time mongo collection changes(which in turn updates the DOM)

```
Template.eventCreate.helpers({
    fields: function(){
        var template = EventTemplate.findOne({name: 'Job Template'});
        console.log("template", template);
        if(template){
            Session.set("template", template);
            template.fields.forEach(function(field, index){
               field.sourceCollectionData = StaticLists.find({_id: field.sourceCollection});
            });
            return template.fields;
        }        
    }
});

Template.eventCreate.rendered = function(){
    $('#newEventForm').validate({
        ...
        ...
    console.log("rendering main template");

   addValidationRules(Session.get('template'));
}
```

Now the console output is something like:

```
template undefined event_create.js?bfeba9389401dac358bc313bd9d4205818e356a1:52
rendering main template event_create.js?bfeba9389401dac358bc313bd9d4205818e356a1:98
template Object {_id: "iFDndmjavtFN8AdGQ", name: "Job Template", description: "Job Template",     fields: Array[13]}
```

which shows that (and I tried it even with a break point in js script) that just when script loads template is undefined and no input field is rendered on front end but rendered callback is invoked. Now later when template gets populated with data, input fields are rendered but callback is not invoked again.

Comment: does that checkbox input render at all?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="{{../label}}" id="{{../label}}" value="{{name}}" {{checked ../defaultValue}}>    that checked part looks wrong

Comment: yes checkbox does get rendered. Actually its happening with all the fields which are rendered inside each block like radio buttons, dropdown options etc. So it looks like to me that each block is the problem here which is rendered later than rendered callback

Comment: I've noticed the same behavior since using blaze, my #each block renders but the callback fires before it has.

Answer (score 1):

The [recommended pattern](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/47Orrrz7kjg/Msfv1wMhEc4J) is to put the **contents** of your {{#each}} blocks in separate templates and tap into the rendered event of *those* templates.

By the way, Meteor.defer is no longer required.

Comment: making separate template for {{#each}} block helps but rendered gives another problem while object is loaded from mongo. I have edited my question for the scenario